# Kubernetes - what does <unset> mean in port in a service?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a service exposed of type=LoadBalancer and when I do a

`kubectl describe services servicename`,

I get this output :

```
Name:           ser1
Namespace:      default
Labels:         app=online1
Selector:       app=online1
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         10.0.0.32
External IPs:       192.168.99.100
Port:           <unset> 8080/TCP
NodePort:       <unset> 30545/TCP
Endpoints:      172.17.0.10:8080,172.17.0.11:8080,172.17.0.8:8080 + 1 more...
Session Affinity:   None
```

Can someone please guide on the following doubts :

1.) I can't understand what `<unset>` means in Port and NodePort. Also, how does it affect my service?

2.) When I want to hit a service, I should hit the service using `<external-ip:NodePort>` right? Then what's the use of Port?

Comment: RE: question 2. I think that you hit the service using `<external-ip:Port>` Since the accepted answer may not have clarified this, and since I am still getting up to speed with kubernetes, I am leaving this as a comment. Others that are more sure might want to edit this into the accepted answer if correct, or follow up with another comment if wrong.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Port unset** means: You didn't specify a name in service creation.

Service Yaml excerpt (note `name: grpc`):

```
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 26257
    targetPort: 26257
    name: grpc
  type: NodePort
```

`kubectl describe services servicename` output excerpt:

```
Type:                   NodePort
IP:                     10.101.87.248
Port:                   grpc    26257/TCP
NodePort:               grpc    31045/TCP
Endpoints:              10.20.12.71:26257,10.20.12.73:26257,10.20.8.81:26257
```

**Port** is definition of container ports that service will send the traffic on (Actual Endpoint).

Comment: Thanks for you answer :) So, the "name" is just for a better reference right? As in <unset> would not do any harm so to say?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help again :)

Comment: I ran 
`kubectl expose deployment <name>  --type=NodePort --port=8081 --target-port=8080`
And I still see **unset** in my describe service output

Comment: @JainamMJ the <name> that you are referring to is the deployment name. The <unset> that is seen in the describe output of a service next to Port/NodePort is the name that we assign to that `port` section under `.spec.ports` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

To answer second part of the question:
`When I want to hit a service, I hit the service using <external-ip:NodePort> right? Then what's the use of Port?`:

A `Service` in k8s is a combination of virtual IP and virtual Port.

Just like we assign an IP to an (ethernet) interface to communicate through it, this Virtual IP:Port combination is a way to communicate through the service.

The `targetPort` is the target container's port. (if not specified, k8s defaults it to the port (virtual port) of the Service)

The `NodePort` is the port that is exposed on an ethernet interface (on which k8s cluster is configured) of the machine. (if not specified, k8s chooses a random available port between 30000-32767 for service types `NodePort` and `LoadBalancer`).

So as you see, while we can ignore `targetPort` or `NodePort`, without the "port" (virtual port) in question, there is no existence of Service.

BTW: these virtual IP and Port of Service lives completely in the IPtables rules (if IPtables is used) along with the forwarding rules from/to node or container through this virtual ip:port.

Please note: `Headless Service` is an exception to this concept.